# Laravel not formatting 3rd party package

Tags: laravel

I've recently set up my Laravel 5.7 project with GIT. I did a clone onto a new computer and ran composer install. I keep getting a syntax error (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING).

I'm using a Upgraded version of Laravel 5.7(started at 5.1). Using the Bican Roles package to manage roles on the site.
I've tried reinstalling and uninstalling the package. Also tried wrapping it with double parentheses. (thats the part not formatting). all to no avail

```
//before rendering in app.blade.php  
@role('admin')
// after rendering  
<?php if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->is'admin'): ?>
```

Errors I'm getting when trying to load the page.

> syntax error, unexpected ''admin'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) (View:
>   C:\wamp64\www\dashboard\resources\views\app.blade.php) (View:
>   C:\wamp64\www\dashboard\resources\views\app.blade.php) Previous
>   exceptions syntax error, unexpected ''admin''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) (View:
>   C:\wamp64\www\dashboard\resources\views\app.blade.php) (0) syntax
>   error, unexpected ''admin'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) (0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part leads to error: `Auth::user()->is'admin'`

It should be `Auth::user()->is('admin')`. You should check the code where the Blade directive `@role` is defined.